# Django saving form strings in database with extra characters (u'string')

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-forms, django-postgresql

I've been having problems in django while trying to save the `form.cleaned_data` in a postgres database.

```
user_instance.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
```

the data is being saved this way `(u'Firstname',)` with the 'u' prefix and parenthesis like if I were saving a tuple in the database.

I've used this tons of times with a mysql database and never happened before,

My django version is 1.3.1

**UPDATE**

i was using commas this way
    user_profile.phone_area = phone_area,
    user_profile.phone_number = phone_number,
    user_profile.email = email,

I edited someone else's source code and forgot to delete the commas, that's why it was generating tuples. Thank you for your help

Comment: Is your postgres database setup to support unicode data?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/

Comment: this is the output of my database psql -l  bmdata    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |

Answer (score 1):

Aside from validation, `form.clean_data()` will perform some implicit conversions to Python data types. You can simply perform an explicit conversion by wrapping the returned value with the `str()` or the `unicode()` built-in. Afterwards, format the string using `strip("(''),")`.

Comment: tried str(form.cleaned_data['first_name']) and nothing, the u just dissapears but the parenthesis stills there

Comment: I forgotten to mention, you will need to strip the resulting string of the tuple artifacts. I carelessly left out this little detail; I will change my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've never needed to do this before to save form data in a database, why now is converting it into a tuple?, I also checked the cleaned_data dictionary and the strings are u'string' unicode strings

Comment: I should also mention, if the resulting tuple contains multiple values you wish to join, use `"".join(form.clean_data())`

Comment: This conversion may have to do with the forms class and how your fields may be structured (if any), I'm not sure; I have not experience this particular behavior myself. From the Django website: "...it is better to access form.cleaned_data. This data has not only been validated but will also be converted in to the relevant Python types for you."- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I updated my original question i found the answer, I'm sorry if I was rude but i had three hours struggling with this and the answer was so ... My bad,